# Did Euler ever use anything similar to Cauchy's inequality?

Tags: ho.history-overview, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

This could be asked more provocatively, indeed how it arose, as "how did Euler do so much mathematics without using and/or knowing Cauchy's inequality?", something that came up in the context when reading a comment about how ubiquitous said inequality/variants is in various fields today.

But I think the title question is at least fact-based, and of historical interest.

Q. Did Euler ever use anything similar to Cauchy's inequality?

Particularly I might have expected something like the integral version (thus with Schwarz's name) to appear somewhere in calculus of variations. Alternatively, something beyond simply a geometric-arithmetic mean might have occurred in number theory arguments. (I figure, as a first go, asking mathematicians is better than historians, especially as if there is "something similar" I'd like to hear it.)

For clarification, it is the Cauchy inequality that appears in Note II [here](http://archive.org/details/bub_gb_OlxT3B6EjykC/page/n461/mode/2up), and not his bounds on derivatives (or Taylor series coefficients).

Comment: Which Cauchy inequality?

Comment: I'm far from an expert on math history, but I would venture that part of the answer is that Euler and his contemporaries were much less focused on proving estimates than modern mathematicians are. Off hand I can think of many more equalities and formulas attributed to Euler and his contemporaries than inequalities. And Cauchy's inequality isn't particularly helpful in proving the former. That said, I would be surprised if there isn't "something similar," as you say, somewhere in his prodigious works.

Comment: That was exactly my feeling too - estimates just weren't vogue back then (partially because Euler didn't do them!)

Comment: There are lots of inequalities in Note II.  Do you mean Theorem 16, the one that says $a \cdot b \le \|a\| \|b\|$?

Comment: following up on @MarkLewko 's comment: one inequality attributed to Euler is a [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem_in_geometry)